# Referencing class in XAML file

Tags: c#, xaml

as a beginner I have a beginner question. It's about a little game called Reversi (Othello).
I want to bind the class called Stone with my XAML file. I intend to use the properties of the class to change the layout of the ellipses. Not sure if it's better to build the 64 ellipses in the .XAML file or at runtime in the .cs file.

I appreciate any strategic help here for my little project. I read many introductions in XAML but just couldn't find a nice example...

```
namespace Reversi
{
    class Stone
    {
        private static int _CountStones;
        public static int CountStones
        {
            get { return _CountStones; }
        }

    private Boolean _Color;
    public Boolean Color
    {
        get { return _Color; }
        set { _Color = value; }
    }
[....]
```

I just cant figure out how to bind these properties in the XAML file.

This is what i have so far:

```
xmlns:sto="clr-namespace:Reversi"
```

And now I want to do something like that:

```
  <Ellipse Name="{Binding ElementName=ID???}" Fill="{Binding Path:Color}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"></Ellipse>
```

I know that the Fill property is of the type Brush and my Color property is Boolean... will build a type converter later but for know I think it describes my problem.

Let me know if you need any further information, I hope this explanation isn't too vague.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First You must learn about DataBiding in WPF.

For Your example. It is only part of the code. It is show how to bind data in WPF.

First You must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to Your `Stone` class like this.

```
public class Stone : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static int _CountStones;
        public static int CountStones
        {
            get { return _CountStones; }
        }

        private Boolean _Color;
        public Boolean Color
        {
            get { return _Color; }
            set {
                if (value == _Color)
                    return;

                _Color = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("Color");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

Next You must bind `Stone` class with xaml view.

Code behind in Your View class

Constructor

```
    public YourViewClassName()
    {
       this.DataSource  = new Stone();
    }
```

Then You may do this

```
<Ellipse Fill="{Binding Color}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"></Ellipse>
```

Color will by bind with `Stone` class property

Some information:

http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/04/05/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-one.html

http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/04/20/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-two.html

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank You very much